# Android String Resource &deg

Tags: android, string, resources

I would like to create a string resource that has the degree symbol.

For example:

```
<string name="celsius">&deg;C</string>
```

but this generates a parsing error.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Mitch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the unicode below to display the symbol for Celcius.

```
<string name="celcius">\u2103</string>
```